# ASP.NET Dynamic SignalR Hubs? groups?

Tags: asp.net, signalr

I have web controls (gauges) I create dynamically 1 to x (max 30) depending on the Job setup on page load. The SignalR Hub code is on a timer that fires every 20 seconds. This way my dynamic gauges get data **every 30 seconds**. I am setting the value for the control with a client javascript function guage.set_vale(). This function loops through every 30 seconds when the hub fires and sets the values.

```
   For i As Integer = 0 To 7
        Dim UserControl As WebUserControl1 = CType(Me.LoadControl("~/WebUserControl1.ascx"), WebUserControl1)
        UserControl.ID = "RG" & (i)  ''1_RadGauge

        UserControl.ControlWidth = 9
        UserControl.setTankNumber = i + 20
        Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(UserControl)

    Next
```

Currently, all controls are getting data from the same single HUB. The data that feeds these controls is a SQL database on the server side.

```
SELECT top(1) * from zSignalR_DB_Test order by id desc
```

So all controls are showing the same data. 
What I want to do is have each control show its data. So each control would be getting its own data from the database

```
    SELECT top(1) * from zSignalR_DB_Test WHERE ID = 'MyControlID' order by id desc
```

I have looked at SignalR Groups but have not seen how to do what I am trying to do. In this way, all I would need to do is associate the controlID with the data in the database.

My questions are:

Do I need a separate SignalR Hub for every control I create dynamically?

Do I need to create those hubs dynamically?

Is SignalR Groups the right way of doing this?

If I am only updating every 30 seconds or a minute could I not just create a method that sends the ID back from the client and as I loop through each control in the client (maybe add a 1 second pause) send the ID a run a different SQL statement?

Any thoughts or examples would be great.

More code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
        var logger = $.connection.loghub;
        logger.client.logMessage = function(msg) { 

            var ajaxPanel = document.getElementById("Panel1");  
            for (var x = 0; x < ajaxPanel.children.length; x=x+2) {  

                if (msg <=50){
                    var ImageElementGreen = ajaxPanel.children[x].children[0];
                    ImageElementGreen.style.visibility = 'visible'
                    var ImageElementRed = ajaxPanel.children[x].children[1];
                    ImageElementRed.style.visibility = 'hidden'
                } else {
                    var ImageElementGreen = ajaxPanel.children[x].children[0];
                    ImageElementGreen.style.visibility = 'hidden'
                    var ImageElementRed = ajaxPanel.children[x].children[1];
                    ImageElementRed.style.visibility = 'visible'
               }

                var TBValueElement = ajaxPanel.children[x].children[3].children[0];
                var TBValue = $find(TBValueElement.id);
                TBValue.set_value(msg + "%");

                var linearGaugeElement = ajaxPanel.children[x].children[4];
                var linearGauge = $find(linearGaugeElement.id);                           
                linearGauge.set_value(msg);  
            }
        };
        $.connection.hub.start();
    });     
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the SignalIR example, it is stated ..
"Once servers are started and clients are connected, messages sent from one client will appear in all connected clients" you would just need to direct the individual client data to the correct UI control or 'gauge'. Create a class to store, format, and access your data.

That being said, SignalIR is based on WebSocket(s), which is a lovely asynchronous 'real-time' service. Websockets are not constrained by the .Net implementation, and where even an arduino can be configured as a client or a server.

If going the websocket route, create some javascript to trigger when ..

```
ws.onmessage = function(e){
  var msg = "";
  var commandstring = "";
  var loadstring = "";
  if(e.data instanceof ArrayBuffer){
    msg = "BIN:";
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(e.data);
    for (var i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
      msg += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
    }
  } 
  else
  {
   msg = e.data;
  }
}
```